# Show other element on hover effect

Tags: css

I am wondering if how could I show other element when the user hovers to a certain element.

For example,

```
<div class = "hoverMe">Hover Me </div>

<div class = "showMe">Hello I'm in show state.</div>

.showMe{ 
   display: none;
}

.hoverMe:hover { 
     // then what to put here?
}
```

If the user hovers on `.hoverMe` the `.showMe` will be shown in pure `css` thankz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`

```
.hoverMe:hover + div {
  display:block;
}
```

From MDN

> It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MDWbE/1/)

Using jQuery, you will have to use the `hover()` function

```
$(".hoverMe").on("hover", function () {
  $(".showMe").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: But what if they are not consecutive div?

Comment: You will have to use jquery, or a more complicated series of selectors

Comment: So that is not posible to do in css but anyway thankz man. :)

Comment: @Nesmar You can do it in CSS. Give me another situation and I will help you figure out the selector for it

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 50 rep yet, so I can't comment on the above answer.

It is possible to do this purely in CSS using the tilde (~);

```
.hoverMe:hover ~ .showMe {
    display: block;
}
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)